Solving the Travelling Salesman Problem by Ant Colony Optimisation
I am currently attempting to implement the Travelling Salesman Problem via the Ant Colony Optimisation Algorithm. I cannot say that I have a good grasp of the algorithm on an intuitive level, but nevertheless I attempted to implement it in Python based on what I could understand. First, we initialise the pheromone levels, then we build them up by setting a number of "ants" through the routes (honestly this idea still eludes me), then we slowly build up the pheromone levels, then "evaporate" them over iterations until we are left with a certain route with the maximum probability, and that is supposed to be our minimum route.
Here is the code I got so far:
Initialising parameters:
import numpy as np


num_cities = len(distance_matrix)
num_ants = 20
num_iterations = 100
decay = 0.5
alpha = 1  
beta = 2  

pheromone_levels = np.ones((num_cities, num_cities)) * 1e-6

Supplementary functions which I will need:
def select_next_city(pheromone_levels, distance_matrix, current_city, visited):
    pheromones = pheromone_levels[current_city] ** alpha
    visibility = np.zeros_like(pheromones) 
    for city in range(num_cities):
        if city not in visited and distance_matrix[current_city][city] != 0:
            visibility[city] = (1.0 / distance_matrix[current_city][city]) ** beta
    probabilities = pheromones * visibility
    probabilities_sum = probabilities.sum()
    if probabilities_sum == 0:
        return np.random.choice([city for city in range(num_cities) if city not in visited])
    probabilities /= probabilities_sum
    return np.random.choice(num_cities, p=probabilities)

def update_pheromones(pheromone_levels, routes, scores):
    for i, route in enumerate(routes):
        for j in range(num_cities - 1):
            pheromone_levels[route[j], route[j+1]] += 1 / scores[i]
        pheromone_levels[route[-1], route[0]] += 1 / scores[i]
    pheromone_levels *= (1 - decay) 

And now the actual looping part:
best_route = None
best_distance = float('inf')

for iteration in range(num_iterations):
    routes = []
    distances = []

    for ant in range(num_ants):
        route = [np.random.randint(num_cities)]
        while len(route) < num_cities:
            current_city = route[-1]
            next_city = select_next_city(pheromone_levels, distance_matrix, current_city, route)
            route.append(next_city)
        routes.append(route)
        route_distance = sum(distance_matrix[route[i]][route[i+1]] for i in range(-1, len(route)-1))
        distances.append(route_distance)

        if route_distance < best_distance:
            best_distance = route_distance
            best_route = route

    update_pheromones(pheromone_levels, routes, distances)

print("Best route:", best_route)
print("Best route distance:", best_distance)

The solution I get leads to a total distance of 76-78, which far exceeds the best known solution of 39 and contradicts my impression of the efficiency of ACO. May I seek any advice on what I might have done wrongly here? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

you only run 100 iterations. Is the result converging and not getting any better? 100 iterations seems rather small to me. It could also be that you are falling into a local minima. Usually problems like this are solved by starting a lot of experiments in parallel, each with a random starting condition, so some of them will avoid bad local minimas and find solutions closer to the optimal.

@Elerium115 Yes, unfortunately after running 10,000 iterations as well, the result appears to be the same. Does not seem to be a iteration count problem here, even though I fully see what you mean!
